# Symbolic links of plist file getting turned into plain text files

Tags: dropbox, symlink

I'm trying to share my Sequel Pro favourites between my iMac and my Macbook Air. The method I'm using is this:

1. On the iMac, ove Favorites.plist from `~/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data` to `~/Dropbox/Apps/Sequel_Pro`;
2. On the iMac, make a symbolic link to the Favorites.plist file (in Dropbox) and move that link into the `~/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data` folder;
3. On the Macbook, make a symbolic link to the Favorites.plist file (in Dropbox) and move that link into the `~/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data` folder

In both steps 2 and 3 I need to rename the symbolic link file from `Favorites.plist symlink` to `Favorites.plist` in order to Sequel Pro to pick up on it.

What I find is that Sequel Pro on both machines opens with the favourites in place, but changes to the favourites are not reflected on the other machine and do not seem to be passed back to the original in Dropbox (there is no 'sync activity' indicator on the Dropbox icon). Further investigation reveals that, after opening Sequel Pro, the act of saving changes to the favourites (or of quitting the app, which I guess updates the favorites.plist as part of the quitting process) apparently changes the symbolic link into a regular text file rather than updating the original.

Is this expected behaviour?

Extra info: OSX 10.9.5, Sequel Pro 1.1

Comment: Yes, it's the expected behavior because Sequel Pro expects the `Favorites.plist` file to be where it's programmed to be, in `~/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data`.

Comment: @user3439894 that's helpful, thanks. If you change your comment to an answer then I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the expected behavior because Sequel Pro expects the `Favorites.plist` file to be where it's programmed to be, in `~/Application Support/Sequel Pro/Data`.

In other words, when Sequel Pro opens, it reads the `Favorites.plist` file following the symlink because it's just making a read of the file.  When a change is make or the app closes the file is updated and is written in its programmed location and does not follow the symlink because first a temporary `Favorites.plist.<$random>` file is written and then the symlink is deleted and the temporary `Favorites.plist.<$random>` file is renamed to `Favorites.plist`.  In this process Sequel Pro sees the symlink of the `Favorites.plist` as a regular file not a symlink and why it's replaced.

Comment: +1 for the clarification regarding the multi-step process of writing the plist file

Answer (score 1):

user3439894 has confirmed that this is expected behaviour. I found a workaround, however, which is to move Favorites.plist’s entire enclosing Data folder into Dropbox and to use that folder as the target for the the symbolic link rather than the individual file. That seems to work fine.

Comment: This works because the symlink is to a directory not an individual file and has to do with the process used to write out `.plist` files.  I added some info to my original answer to help explain.  BTW If Dropbox is unavailable the symlink to the Data folder might get deleted and the folder recreated at it original location, do make sure Dropbox is online before opening/closing Sequel Pro.